# React navigation state resets

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-native-web

When I refresh the page on web, the navigation state is lost therefore I can't navigate back. What I want to happen is If I refresh the page, the navigation state won't be lost. What I tried doing was persisting state to local storage following the docs:

```
useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * Get and sets the persisted navigation state so
     *  the user is immediately returned to the same location after the app is restarted.
     */
    const restoreState = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        if (initialUrl == null) {
          const savedStateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);

          const state = savedStateString
            ? JSON.parse(savedStateString)
            : undefined;

          if (state !== undefined) {
            setInitialState(state);
          }
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReady(true);
      }
    };
    if (!isReady) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isReady]);
```

This is what my container looks like:

```
        <NavigationContainer
          linking={linking}
          theme={true ? navigationTheme.light : navigationTheme.dark}
          initialState={initialState}
          onStateChange={(state) => state && handleNavigationChange(state)}
          ref={navigation}>
```

```
  const handleNavigationChange = async (state: NavigationState): Promise<void> => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state));
  };
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing after persisting state in local storage?

Comment: @Srishti The navigation state is lost when I refresh the page, but the navigation state did persist in local storage